# How I can display anchor tag or button in react-data-components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am very new to React word. I am using react-data-components to display data in my page.

I am displaying user information in this data table and want to provide "Edit" link, so I can update user information.

Below is my DataTable

FirstName LastName Action
John      Michel    Edit
Mark      Cuban     Edit

As per github documentation, Data-table simply accept columns object with property, and render data accordingly. https://github.com/carlosrocha/react-data-components.

Any help would be appreciate !!!

Comment: Please upload the code you have written already to try achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out. I am posting answer if anyone phase the same problem. I found this example from github:https://github.com/carlosrocha/react-data-components/blob/HEAD/example/table/main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { DataTable } from 'react-data-components';

function buildTable(data) {
  const renderMapUrl =
    (val, row) =>
      <a href={`https://www.google.com/maps?q=${row['lat']},${row['long']}`}>
        Google Maps
      </a>;

  const tableColumns = [
    { title: 'Name', prop: 'name' },
    { title: 'City', prop: 'city' },
    { title: 'Street address', prop: 'street' },
    { title: 'Phone', prop: 'phone', defaultContent: '<no phone>' },
    { title: 'Map', render: renderMapUrl, className: 'text-center' },
  ];

  return (
    <DataTable
      className="container"
      keys="id"
      columns={tableColumns}
      initialData={data}
      initialPageLength={5}
      initialSortBy={{ prop: 'city', order: 'descending' }}
      pageLengthOptions={[ 5, 20, 50 ]}
    />
  );
}

fetch('/data.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((rows) => {
    ReactDOM.render(buildTable(rows), document.getElementById('root'));
  });
```